# Подсчет количества объектов класса

Tags: java

Создал статическое поле `boxCount` и конструктор в классе `Box`. Сделал вывод в классе `Main`, но почему-то результат - число 0. Хотя создано 3 объекта. В чем может быть проблема?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Кол-во коробок = " + Box.getBoxCount());

        Box firstBox = new Box(0.2, 1.4, 2.4);
        Box secondBox = new Box(2.3, 0.8, 3.2);
        Box thirdBox = new Box(1.3, 0.6, 1.2);
    }
}


public class Box {

    private static int boxCount;
    private double width;
    private double height;
    private double depth;

    public Box() {
        boxCount++;
    }

    public static int getBoxCount() {
        return boxCount;
    }

    public Box(double width, double height, double depth) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.depth = depth;
    }
}
```

Comment: А почему у вас вывод количества идет перед созданием объектов?

Comment: Просто чтобы строчка с кодом сразу была перед глазами и не терялась в ниже написаном коде

Comment: Вам idea подсказывает что конструктор, в котором у вас инкремент, не используется. В конструкторе с параметрами у вас инкремент присутствует?

Comment: У меня отсутствует конструктор с какими-либо параметрами. Всего есть в классе один конструктор, который представлен на скриншоте.

Comment: Добавьте весь код в вопрос текстом, а не скриншотами. Если у вас нет конструктора с параметрами, то код вообще не соберется.

Comment: То что строчка "перед глазами" и есть причина того что выводит 0. Потому что она выполнится еще до того как объекты созданы. Порядок строк имеет значение.

Comment: Ну как же один конструктор, а `public Box(double width, double height, double depth)` - это что по-вашему? В нем `boxCount` не инкрементируется, поэтому количество созданных объектов и не считается.

Comment: В данной ситуации порядок записи кода, по всей видимости, не имеет значения, ибо что запить System.out.println("Кол-во коробок = " + Box.getBoxCount());  под объектами, либо над объектами будет выдавать одинаковый результат - 0.

Comment: Вы занимаетесь "вегетативным" программированием, это плохой подход. Порядок строк важен, а 0 у вас был, из-за того что вы не разобрались в конструкторах

Comment: Спасибо за замечание, все таки порядо был важен. Возьму это на вооружение.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public Box(double width, double height, double depth) {
    this(); // !!!
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.depth = depth;
}
```

Это называется *constructor chaining*.

Comment: Cпасибо, изменил, заработало.

Comment: @T1mmy Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.